# Form with variable dropdown based on entries in column

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I created a form in Excel VBA. I want a dropdown list with a variable input.

Currently this is set to Site1, Site2 and Site3.

I would like to retrieve this from sheet "Sources" in range A:A. The list might grow in the future so would like that it takes all inputs in A:A into account.

In module1, I have below code:

```vb
Sub EnterPurchaseOrder()

...
        
        Call ShowUserForm

...    

End Sub
```

```vb
Sub ShowUserForm()
    Dim myForm As New createPurchaseOrder
    myForm.Show
End Sub
```

```vb
function findQuantity() as double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Declare variables
Dim quantity As Double

quantity = ActiveCell.Value

findQuantity = quantity

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I also have a form called "createPurchaseOrder" with the following code:

```vb
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
Dim orderQty As Double

orderQty = findQuantity

    purchOrd.Value = ""
    
    sourceDropDown.Clear
    With sourceDropDown
        .AddItem "Site1"
        .AddItem "Site2"
        .AddItem "Site3"
    End With
    
    mmCode = ""
    
    orderQuantity = orderQty
    
    releaseDate = ""
    
    purchOrd.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```vb
    With sourceDropDown
        .AddItem "Site1"
        .AddItem "Site2"
        .AddItem "Site3"
    End With
```

Try this

```vb
  Dim wsSource As Worksheet
  Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sources")

  With wsSource
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  End With

  sourceDropDown.List = wsSource.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value
```